# How to map textarea tags to pdf fields (regular pdf or pdf as an image)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, .net

I want to create a fillable pdf document that allows the user to submit the information to a server. I am wondering if there is a good way to map pdf fields to `<textarea>` or `<input>`. I want a text area that I can prepopulate with data from the database and the user can also edit whatever they see fit and submit the new updated values to my server.

The only way I can think of right now is taking screenshots of the pdf and manually mapping tags to each field.

I tried using map and area tags in html but I couldn't put text there or allow the user to edit the text as shown below:

```
<img src="/sales_1.png" usemap="#image-map">
<map name="image-map" style="position: absolute;">
    <area alt="" title="" href="" coords="717,210,992,286" shape="rect"><text>asdfasdf</text><area/>
    <area coords="43,329,293,404" shape="rect">
    <area coords="446,328,715,402" shape="rect">
</map>
```

I am developing a .net website.

Comment: Are you trying to update/populate the PDF file as the user is making changes or after they click a Submit button?  Are you in control of the PDF file and can add text fields to it for population?

Comment: I would like to prepopulate it with some data that the user can update or edit as they are making changes. Yes I am in control of the PDF file. Thanks.